# autocomment (trivial answer) bug

Tags: support, bug, asking-questions

I've tried 6 times to post my answer to

- [Cannot edit Initiation Form of Designer Workflows with InfoPath](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14571/cannot-edit-initiation-form-of-designer-workflows-with-infopath)

and it repeatedly was being posted as comment instead (I removed duplicated comments though).

And whenever I am trying to open the URL of question

- _https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14571/cannot-edit-initiation-form-of-designer-workflows-with-infopath

by copy-pasting into browser address/navigation textbox (tried in Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, etc), it is always redirected to

- _https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14571/cannot-edit-initiation-form-of-designer-workflows-with-infopath#autocomment43464

with a "autocomment" in URL, even in browser where I am not logged-in.

This is the first time I encounter this problem after many years in SE sites.
What is autocomment and how can I post my answer?

Update:
Well, I managed to post my answer after adding more phrases to it. But why more simple another answer to the same question (with less number of words and without any reference) was not considered trivial and posted as autocomment?

Why is my more elaborated answer (in comparison to another published answer, with more words and having a link/reference)  posted as autocomment and I need to bloat it by dummy phrases in order to be published as answer?